# Differentiate Chapter Headings in ToC and Body

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, titlesec

Working on formatting a thesis (using the book class) and I need to format the TOC entries and the actually chapter headings in very different ways.

For the ToC, entires are in all caps and use roman numerals:

```
ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS................ii
CHAPTER
   I.  INTRODUCTION..............1
   II. TITLE OF CHAPTER ONE......7
BIBLIOGRAPHY....................45
```

Meanwhile, the actually pages for the chapters center the heading, spell out `chapter,' and place the title on a new line in all caps:

```
        CHAPTER I
    TITLE OF CHAPTER 1
Text of chapter....
```

I am used to using titlesec, but haven't done anything this complex where you control the formatting in two different places.  What package would you use to execute this in LaTeX and how would you proceed?

Comment: For the table of contents, I would use `titletoc`. The formatting of thetoc is independent of  the `\titleformat` details (except the`Table of Contents` title).

Comment: That would be what I'm looking for.